# setting storage connection string dynamically Azure function V1

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I am following a design in which I am not saving any storage connection string in config file rather we should get it from azure key vault.We have implemented this in web jobs.

I am using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.11. and net framework 4.6.1.

in the applications settings of function app we have to set AzureWebJobsStorage.

How can I dynamically set the value to the storage settings in function app code?

Comment: You can check this link for more information about key vault integration: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/. Also Storage account supports RBAC so depends on your use case you dont need to store the connectionstring: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi. You can activate Managed Identity on your function app

Answer (score -1):

have you considered using Azure management api?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings

Comment: Hi this link does not point to API Management documentation ?

Comment: Ok. Like how WebJobs can access configuration values and update it before it starts to execute. Functions v1 do not have any start up class where we can change the storage account connection string dynamically.

Comment: another way is to use Secret Identifier. Please read more here: https://www.mikkelhm.dk/archive/securing-your-secrets-with-azure-key-vault-part-6-azure-functions/